# Setting minifyEnabled to true causes problems with dates in Android app

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

I tried to configure proguard in my Android app (setting minifyEnabled to true in my Gradle file). This causes strange behaviour with some date conversions (I convert some datetimes in SQLite to Unix Epoch times (long)). Datetimes are all converted to Epoch time 0 when setting minifyEnabled to true. When setting minifyEnabled to false, conversions works normal. I have no custom rules in my Proguard file, everything is default. Has somebody an explanation for this?

Comment: show your Proguard contents

Comment: Make sure https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets/blob/master/libraries/proguard-sqlite.pro